# PERL XPath Parser Help

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

I want to pull in data using a XML::XPath parser from a XML DB file from the Worldbank site. The problem is that I'm not seeing any results in the output. I must be missing something in the code. Ideally, I would like to extract just the death rate statistics from each country XML DB (year and value). I'm using this as part of my input:

http://data.worldbank.org/sites/default/files/countries/en/afghanistan_en.xml

```
use strict;
use LWP 5.64;
use HTML::ContentExtractor;
use XML::XPath;

my $agent1 = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $extractor = HTML::ContentExtractor->new();

#Retrieve main Worldbank country site
my $mainlink = "http://data.worldbank.org/country/";
my $page = $agent1->get("$mainlink");
my $fulltext = $page->decoded_content();

#Match to just all available countries in Worldbank
my $country = "";
my @countryList;
if (@countryList = $fulltext =~ m/(http:\/\/data\.worldbank\.org\/country\/.*?")/gi){
    foreach $country(@countryList){
        #Remove " at the end of link
        $country=~s/\"//gi;
        print "\n" . $country;

        #Retrieve each country profile's XML DB file
        my $page = $agent1->get("$country");
        my $fulltext = $page->decoded_content();
        my $XML_DB = "";
        my @countryXMLDBList;

        if (@countryXMLDBList = $fulltext =~ m/(http:\/\/data\.worldbank\.org\/sites\/default\/files\/countries\/en\/.*?\.xml)/gi){
            foreach $XML_DB(@countryXMLDBList){

                my $page = $agent1->get("$XML_DB");
                my $fulltext = $page->decoded_content();
                #print $fulltext; 
                #Use XML XPath parser to find elements related to death rate
                my $xp = XML::XPath->new($fulltext); #my $xp = XML::XPath->new("afghanistan_en.xml"); 
                my $nodeSet = $xp->find("//*");
                if (!$nodeSet->isa('XML::XPath::NodeSet') || $nodeSet->size() == 0) {
                    #No match found
                    print "\nMatch not found!";
                    exit;
                } else {
                    foreach my $node ($nodeSet->get_nodelist){
                        print "\n" . $node->find('country')->string_value;
                        print "\n" . $node->find('indicator')->string_value;
                        print "\n" . $node->find('year')->string_value;
                        print "\n" . $node->find('value')->string_value;
                        exit;
                    }
                }
            }
            #Build line graph based on death rate statistics and output some image file format
        }
    }
}
```

I am also looking into using the xpath expression "following-sibling", but not sure how to use it correctly. For example, I have the following set of XML data where I am only interested in pulling siblings directly after the indicator for just death rate data.

```
<data>
<country id="AFG">Afghanistan</country>
<indicator id="SP.DYN.CDRT.IN">Death rate, crude (per 1,000 people)</indicator>
<year>2006</year>
<value>20.3410000</value>
</data>
−
<data>
<country id="AFG">Afghanistan</country>
<indicator id="SP.DYN.CDRT.IN">Death rate, crude (per 1,000 people)</indicator>
<year>2007</year>
<value>19.9480000</value>
</data>
−
<data>
<country id="AFG">Afghanistan</country>
<indicator id="SP.DYN.CDRT.IN">Death rate, crude (per 1,000 people)</indicator>
<year>2008</year>
<value>19.5720000</value>
</data>
−
<data>
<country id="AFG">Afghanistan</country>
<indicator id="IC.EXP.DOCS">Documents to export (number)</indicator>
<year>2005</year>
<value>7.0000000</value>
</data>
−
<data>
<country id="AFG">Afghanistan</country>
<indicator id="IC.EXP.DOCS">Documents to export (number)</indicator>
<year>2006</year>
<value>12.0000000</value>
</data>
−
<data>
<country id="AFG">Afghanistan</country>
<indicator id="IC.EXP.DOCS">Documents to export (number)</indicator>
<year>2007</year>
<value>12.0000000</value>
</data>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: You need to specify your question. What is it that you're having trouble with? Please edit your question to include it.

Comment: Sorry about that...now I've outlined the problem a bit more!

Comment: You probably don't want to be using XML::XPath - the module is old, slow and no longer actively maintained.  I recommend you switch to XML::LibXML.  The API is almost identical but it's much faster and better supported.

Comment: Try replacing `my $nodeSet = $xp->find("//*"); ` with: `my $nodeSet = $xp->find("/*/data"); ` or `my $nodeSet = $xp->find("/*"); `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I dont understand the first part of the question -- it says that**:

> I'm not seeing any results in the
>   output. I must be missing something in
>   the code.

**However, this is not a question at all**. Especially, when there is no input data provided, and no definition of "results".

**For the second part**:

> I am also looking into using the xpath
>   expression "following-sibling", but
>   not sure how to use it correctly. For
>   example, I have the following set of
>   XML data where I am only interested in
>   pulling siblings directly after the
>   indicator for just death rate data.

**Use the following XPath expressions** (supposing that the `data` elements are children of the top element of the XML document:

`/*/data/indicator[@id = 'SP.DYN.CDRT.IN']/following-sibling::*`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out! By the way, I've updated the first part of my question for you.